# i am help for create MATERIALIZED VIEW in postgres but error?

Tags: postgresql

**I wanted create MATERIALIZED VIEW fore up to speed read tables.**

this is method

i am 4 tables

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u2Hhd.png)

**and create a MATERIALIZED VIEW**

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW v_tbmv 
AS 
SELECT id,name tname, bname, mname, vname FROM type left join(select  berand.type_id, berand.name bname,mname,vname from berand left join (select   model.name mname, versions.name vname,model.berand_id from model left join  versions on versions.model_id = model.id) m on berand.id = m.berand_id) b on  b.type_id = type.id;
```

**after create function for refresh MATERIALIZED VIEW**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION fn_refresh_v_tbmv()
RETURNS trigger LANGUAGE plpgsql AS $$
BEGIN
REFRESH MATERIALIZED VIEW v_tbmv;
RETURN NULL;
END;
$$;
```

**create trigger with chnage tables after refresh MATERIALIZED VIEW**

```
CREATE TRIGGER tg_refresh_v_tbmv_type AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE OR DELETE
ON type
FOR EACH STATEMENT EXECUTE PROCEDURE fn_refresh_v_tbmv();
```

**but when update table error**

```
update type set name='sony' where id = 25
```

ERROR:  cannot refresh materialized view "public.v_type" concurrently
HINT:  Create a unique index with no WHERE clause on one or more columns of the materialized view.
CONTEXT:  SQL statement "REFRESH MATERIALIZED VIEW CONCURRENTLY v_type"
PL/pgSQL function fn_refresh_v_type() line 3 at SQL statement

Comment: The error message does not fit your definitions.

Comment: "I wanted create MATERIALIZED VIEW fore up to speed read tables." Why? If your queries are fast (enough) you don't need materialised views like this. Your insert, update and delete queries will now be extremely slow. Why don't you try to optimise your SELECT statements first?

Comment: As explained by @Bergi, the error message refers to the sql statement `REFRESH MATERIALIZED VIEW CONCURRENTLY v_tbmv` which is different from your definition, see the [manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-refreshmaterializedview.html). On the other hand, be carefull with the `RETURN NULL` statement which will cancel any action on table `type`. It should be replaced by `RETURN NEW` for the `INSERT` and `UPDATE` triggers, and by `RETURN OLD` for the `DELETE` trigger.

Comment: i  run bellow sql

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION fn_refresh_v_tbmv2()
RETURNS trigger LANGUAGE plpgsql AS $$
BEGIN
    REFRESH MATERIALIZED VIEW CONCURRENTLY  v_tbmv;
    RETURN old;
END;
$$;

CREATE TRIGGER tg_refresh_v_tbmv_type2 AFTER delete
ON type
FOR EACH STATEMENT EXECUTE PROCEDURE fn_refresh_v_tbmv2();


delete from type where id = 25

ERROR

Comment: ERROR:  cannot refresh materialized view "public.v_tbmv" concurrently
HINT:  Create a unique index with no WHERE clause on one or more columns of the materialized view.
CONTEXT:  SQL statement "REFRESH MATERIALIZED VIEW CONCURRENTLY  v_tbmv"
PL/pgSQL function fn_refresh_v_tbmv2() line 3 at SQL statement